# how to make checkbox property true using JSTL

Tags: liferay, jstl

**How can I make checkbox selected if `<c:when>` condition is true?**

```
<c:set var="status" value="${expData.status}" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${status == 'Business Unit Approal'}">
        <aui:input cssClass="custom-control-input expense select-all" type="checkbox"
            data-amount="${expData.expenseAmount}" data-expenseid="${expData.expenseId}"
            id="expenseCheckbox" name="expenseCheckbox" label="" checked="checked" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <aui:input cssClass="custom-control-input expense select-all" type="checkbox"
            data-amount="${expData.expenseAmount}"data-expenseid="${expData.expenseId}"
            id="expenseCheckbox" name="expenseCheckbox" label="" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I think so my condition is not working for `<c:when>`

Comment: Set your condition in `value` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `<c:choose>` for this. Just set your condition as `value` for the checkbox as following:

```
<aui:input type="checkbox" id="expenseCheckbox" name="expenseCheckbox"
    label="" value="${status == 'Business Unit Approal'}"
    data-amount="${expData.expenseAmount}" data-expenseid="${expData.expenseId}"
    cssClass="custom-control-input expense select-all" />
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. i got to know new thing.

Comment: You are welcome! Also, no need to use `name` attribute, if you are using `id` attribute with same value. Because, `aui` generates the name attribute as per id attribute automatically.